# Creating equally sized (in cm!) geom_rect with a facet_grid with free axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

This is my first post so let me know if anything is wrong.

I have a somewhat stupid problem with creating an equally sized (in cm!) geom_rect when I have a facet_grid with a free axis. See the below example code, where the grey geom_rects are a different size (Obviously because I've specified that):

```
data("mtcars")
library("tidyverse")

mtcars$mpg <- mtcars$mpg + 1000
mtcars <- pivot_longer(mtcars, cols = c(mpg,carb),
                         names_to = "Measure", values_to = "Value")

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = cyl, y = Value), colour = "mediumvioletred", size=3, shape=1) +
  facet_grid(Measure ~ cyl, scales = "free")
p

boxes <- data.frame(Measure = c("carb", "mpg"), start = c(4, 1020), end = c(6, 1030))

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = cyl, y = Value), colour = "mediumvioletred", size=3, shape=1) +
  geom_rect(data = boxes, mapping = aes(xmin=-Inf,xmax=Inf,ymin=start,ymax=end), alpha=0.1) +
  facet_grid(Measure ~ cyl, scales = "free")
p

ggsave(plot = p, filename = "test.png")
```

[The plot that happens with the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnL8F.png)

I want the sizes of the geom_rects to be defined by their ultimate size in the plot, and not the y axes. I'm almost certain its impossible, but maybe anyone here has an idea/solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you mean by "equally sized (in cm!)" and "defined by their ultimate size in the plot"? Also, in what specific way(s) is the output different from what you want?

Comment: Are you looking for the `space = "free_y"` argument in `facet_grid()`?

Comment: No, I already have "free_y" axes. What I want is the geom_boxes to have the same size in the plot, for which they will need to have separate y-ranges. I could sort off eyeball it, but instead I was wondering if there's any better way to do this to get it exactly the same size?